# Geometric distribution

Tags: limits, random-variables

I am trying to solve following question, but I am stuck.

Let $X = Y/n$ where $Y$ is Geom($1/n$) random variable. Find the distribution function of $X$ and find its limit as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: If the support of $Y$ is $Y \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, \}$, then what is the support of $X = Y/n$?  If you know $\Pr[Y = y]$, then what is $\Pr[X = y/n]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Y\sim Geom(1/n)$ you have that $$P(Y=k)=\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{k-1}$$ for $y \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$. Thus $$P(X=k)=P\left(\dfrac{Y}{n}=k\right)=P(Y=nk)=\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{nk-1}$$ for $k\in \{0/n, 1/n, 2/n, 3/n, \ldots\}$. Now $$P(X>k)=P(Y>nk)=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{nk}=\left(\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)}{n}\right)^n\right)^k\to \left(e^{-1}\right)^k=e^{-k}$$ as $n \to \infty$, or equivalently $$P(X\le k) \to 1-e^{-k}$$ which means that $X$ is asymptotically exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda=1$.